# Spring Neo4j Saving MultipartFile

Tags: java, spring, file, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'd like to know what's the best way to store a **MultipartFile** (`org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile`) field into Neo4j db.

It seems I should convert it (`org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter`) somehow. Maybe to a `String[]`.

My use case is: I have a node `Person` who has a `photo` property (MultipartFile).
Then, I'd like to store and retrieve the `photo`.

Should I save it into the FileSystem? Why?
Does anyone have any tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile`... So the question is what do you want to save in the database? The whole file including binary raw data?

Although it is [possibe to save byte[]](http://api.neo4j.org/1.8/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29), I wouldn't recommend it. Instead I suggest to store the files into filesystem and keep only a few relevant data in the database (e.g. the filename, storage location, file size, content-type and so forth).

Furthermore you'll need some kind of mapping from `MultipartFile` to the specific `PropertyContainer` ([Node](http://api.neo4j.org/1.8/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html) or [Relationship](http://api.neo4j.org/1.8/org/neo4j/graphdb/Relationship.html)).

I suggest to check out SDN: http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j